# Angular UI Router: navigation links with sub navs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to create a dynamic tree style navigation.

The basic layout would be something like:

```
    - page 1
    -- page 1-1
    -- page 1-2
    -- page 1-3
    - page 2
    -- page 2-1
    -- page 2-2
    -- page 2-3
    - page 3
    -- page 3-1
    -- page 3-2
    -- page 3-3
```

By default you only see the main links:

```
    - page 1
    - page 2
    - page 3
```

Then you click a link and get the content for that page and its sub links appear:

```
    - page 1
    -- page 1-1
    -- page 1-2
    -- page 1-3
    - page 2
    - page 3
```

When I first started working on this I was creating static states for each main page and a dynamic route for the sub pages that were loaded via a view:

```
    .state('page1',{
      url: '/page1',
      views: {
        'page1Menu': {
          templateUrl: 'views/page1.menu.htm',
          controller: 'page1MenuCtrl'
        },
        'page1Content': {
          templateUrl: 'views/page1.content.htm',
          controller: 'page1ContentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    ... (repeated for page2 and page3)
    .state('page1.info',{
      url: '/:info',
      views: {
        'page1Menu': {
          templateUrl: 'views/page1.menu.htm',
          controller: 'page1MenuCtrl'
        },
        'page1Content': {
          templateUrl: 'views/page1info.content.htm',
          controller: 'page1InfoContentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

And that behaved the way I wanted but was not ultimately how I wanted to handle something like this. Imagine having to create a new set of states for every new section with a potential for having hundreds of sections. And what if the tree goes deeper than just one level?

After attempting to build a third level into this it became obvious that it would not be a sustainable setup (at least in terms of efficiency when expanding content).

So I changed the setup to be fully dynamic, meaning every state after the first is dynamic. But in doing that I now cannot figure out how to get the sub links to appear when clicking on a main link.

If I use a view like before they have to be uniquely named and I have no idea how I'd associate anything without going right back to having to make a bunch of static declarations of states/controllers/etc.

I looked into trying to use ng-class="{active: $state.includes('whatever')}" but that didn't work no matter how I tried it. I have a feeling it was because that was on the same level as the triggering link:

```
    start state link container
      state link
      sub links container with ng-class
    end state link container
```

I have tried to create a Plunkr for this to illustrate what I'm trying to do but I can't ever get it to work the way it works on my server.

Because of that I'm hoping that this information is enough to get the idea across and find a method that makes this work the way I am hoping it will.

Question 1: How do I get the sub navs to only show up when the parent or one of its children is active?

Question 2: How can a set of dynamic states be efficiently expanded to new and varied (in quantity) levels?

---

**Update: More info about Question 2**
The idea here is to create a kind of information reference (a wiki without being a wiki). Some topic groups only have specific topics under them while others have sub groups before reaching the specific topics. For example, the People group would be an alphabetical list of people but the Technology group would be broken into sub groups like Transportation or Medical. And those groups could be split into others like Land, Sea, and Air or Pharmaceutical and Surgical.

In a situation like this, it's unclear just how many levels would be necessary for all topics. It may be that my idea of using dynamic states from the top down just will not work at all. I can see reasons why that could be the case so my question should probably have been "Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?" instead of "How".

Going by Bonatoc's suggestion, it sounds like it may be better to make the first tier of states static and then each sub tier could be made as dynamic as it needs to be, with planning for a static depth for each.

Comment: Looks like you need to build your URLs and your "main" state like so : .../page/[$page]/section/[$section]. Then you intercept your passed (or not passed) vars from the .state statement.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that would solve the problem. Seems more like a lateral move than a solution. Maybe if you provided more information about how that would address the issues I'm having?

Comment: Q1 : it's better to have your states URLs (controller) tied to your nav (layotu), so you can pre-post process them at will. I would then use ng-class with boolean triggered by the controller's data to hide/show/fade/slide/whatever them.

Comment: Q2 : That's what I'm saying. Since you don't know from start how many levels you want to deal with... It's bad software design, UNLESS your tree list is to be parsed by a machine. If you cross the maximum of 4 generations, the user's mind gets distracted from the process. I would not present an interface to users with more than 4 levels. It means something is wrong upstream. Don't take it bad, but it does seem from what I understand that you are maybe flexing your code muscles too hard. And if it's a requirement, I would split by slashes the URLs using toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams.

Comment: I like your answer to Q1, I'll do that. For Q2, I'm going to add more information to my question because I'm not sure if you're answering the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a [nav tree](http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs3_ng120_test_page.html)?

Comment: Looking at that it seems like it might be a good alternative but I'm not ready to give up on this yet.